# Problems with doctrine(order by list) ("Positional parameter at index 3 does not have a bound value.")

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am making right now my own project and got the problem of ordering the entities by list.
I am getting error An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Positional parameter at index 3 does not have a bound value.").

Here is my controller part of code:

```
$em = $doctrine->getManager();

// get the user repository
$realEstateRepo = $em->getRepository(RealEstateAd::class);

$userAdmin = $this->getUser() && $this->getUser()->isAdmin();


// build the query for the doctrine paginator
$query = $realEstateRepo->createQueryBuilder('rea');

$query->leftJoin("rea.realEstate", "re");

$parameters = [];

if (!$userAdmin) {
   $parameters = [
      'deleted' => false,
      'realEstateDeleted' => false
   ];

   $query->where('rea.deleted = :deleted')
       ->andWhere('re.deleted = :realEstateDeleted')
       ->setParameters($parameters);
}

$parameters = array_merge($parameters, [
   'statuses' => [
       Util::REAL_ESTATE_STATUS_AVAILABLE,
       Util::REAL_ESTATE_STATUS_RESERVED,
       Util::REAL_ESTATE_STATUS_LET_AGREED
   ]
]);

$query->add('orderBy', 'FIELD(re.status, :statuses)');

$query->addOrderBy('rea.createdAt', 'DESC')->setParameters($parameters);

$query->getQuery();

$pageSize = 10;

$allRealEstate = new Paginator($query);

$totalItems = count($allRealEstate);

$pagesCount = ceil($totalItems / $pageSize);

if ($page > $pagesCount && $pagesCount != 0) {
   return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
}

$allRealEstate
   ->getQuery()
   ->setFirstResult($pageSize * ($page-1))
   ->setMaxResults($pageSize);

return $this->render('site/home.html.twig', [
   'pageCount' => $pagesCount,
   'page' => $page,
   'realEstate' => $allRealEstate
]);
```

Here is my FIELD function code:

```
<?php

namespace App\DQL\Mysql;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class FieldFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    private $field = null;

    private $values = [];

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser): void
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        // Do the field.
        $this->field = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        // Add the strings to the values array. FIELD must
        // be used with at least 1 string not including the field.

        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();

        while (count($this->values) < 1 ||
            $lexer->lookahead['type'] != Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS) {
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
            $this->values[] = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        }

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker): string
    {
        $query = 'FIELD(';

        $query .= $this->field->dispatch($sqlWalker);

        $query .= ', ';

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->values); $i++) {
            if ($i > 0) {
                $query .= ', ';
            }

            $query .= $this->values[$i]->dispatch($sqlWalker);
        }

        $query .= ')';

        return $query;
    }
}
```

And here is my field function declaration:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                FIELD: App\DQL\Mysql\FieldFunction
```

[My doctrine queries without list ordering(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcoXp.png)
[My doctrine queries without list ordering(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvnHF.png)
[My doctrine queries without list ordering(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApJQX.png)

[My doctrine queries with list ordering(there are only one query and after there are nothing at all)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib8Mx.png)

I was trying to add some ordering by status before ordering by list cause I thought that it is problem that my doctrine do not select status field(and tries to order it)

Comment: I dont see any paramters set for `$query->add('orderBy', 'FIELD(re.status, :statuses)');` That might be your issue.

Comment: There are parameters for them after $query->addOrderBy